# django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: django

When I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get this error

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 209, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default="sqlite:///{}".format(
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db/db.sqlite3')
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically there are two answers, either user which running server don't have rights to open database file.
You can try to fix this by:

```
sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /path/to/dir/db/db.sqlite3
```

Or you don't have this file, you can create it by applying migrate command:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Can you check that  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db/db.sqlite3'), and you path is equal?

Answer (score 11):

Suffering for a while from the same issue and I believe I have found a solution, finally!

```
sudo python manage.py runserver
```

and that did the trick for me.

My permissions were telling me that everything is how it should be.  Regardless, I still had to type in **sudo** at the beginning of the command at the terminal.

Comment: This can be done only in development not helpful in production when Django is deployed on apache server with mod_wsgi

Comment: Didn't help at all. My user was able to access the database. Better check the permissions than use root account for that.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, just solved it. Make sure www-data (or whatever daemon running your web server) has access to both the db.sqlite3 file, and also the path to it. So:

```
sudo chown :www-data <project_folder>/
sudo chown :www-data <project_folder>/db.sqlite3
sudo chmod 664 <project_folder>/db.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the first db in your settings.py file.

You have `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db/db.sqlite3')` if you remove the first `db`, you'll have `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')`

Your database settings will be

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default="sqlite:///{}".format(
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TO ANY WINDOWS USERS:

I got the same error while creating my first django project. I couldn't use `sudo` on windows, so the command `python manage.py runserver` only worked when I ran my terminal as administrator.

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that I had two settings files; one for production and one for development. In my manage.py, I'd specified the deployment settings file and forgotten to add manage.py to my .gitignore, so when I ran the project locally it failed when trying to find the production database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing this problem on AWS EC2 node and using apache, to solve the problem I had to:

```
chown -R apache:apache project_folder
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem.

You just run command with sudo

```
sudo python3 manage.py runserver
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

For many users(like myself), who might have this error while using another DB engine but have set the default engine via your env variable invocation as  `sqllite3`, you might want to either remove that default value or check that the env variable you're checking is named the same way in your `.env` file.

Rookie mistake but well,

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was to use double forward slash instead of triple forward slash:

`I had to change:`

```
os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", f"sqlite://{BASE_DIR}/db.sqlite3")
```

`To:`

```
os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", f"sqlite:///{BASE_DIR}/db.sqlite3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `sudo` for this. The solution is to create a 'db' folder in your project root directory before running the migrate command.
Apparently, 'manage.py' does not have permission to create folders on your machine, so create the folder and everything should work.

Answer (score -1):

@whinytween96 : I have seen this problem occur more when `sudo` is used to run some commands and not for others. You need to be consistent with the usage of `sudo` to fix this problem. I had the DB issue and I fixed it by running the command again with `sudo` prefixed.

i.e.

1. `sudo python manage.py runserver`
2. `sudo python manage.py makemigrations`
3. `sudo python manage.py migrate`

fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

check folder name, you store database file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).