# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f8c05fc8a28>

Tags: django

```
nandu@nandu-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~/Django/newproject$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f8c05fc8a28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 204, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Comment: show your settings for database from setting.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959337/django-db-utils-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file)

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}